# KendoUI TimePicker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI and the time picker is not showing a value also there is a value.

I'm using ASP MVC 4 and loading passing model data to the view. All the data is there in the model.. but for a reason i cannot explain the actual UI is not showing the time.

Code in HTML-View Binding Model to KendoUI:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime)
                            @(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.StartTime)
                                .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))
                            )
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime)
                        @Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.EndTime)
```

[image]

JS: For startChange

```
function startChange() {
    var startTime = this.value(),
        endPicker = $("#EndTime").data("kendoTimePicker");

    if (startTime) {
        startTime = new Date(startTime);

        endPicker.max(startTime);
        startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + this.options.interval);
        endPicker.min(startTime);
        startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + 450);
        endPicker.value(startTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but can happen if the kendo theme is generated via custom theme creator page- is there anything when you highlight the text box after selecting a value? - the color could be white

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select the time value, then it will bind with your model,
then try for this: use the **.text()** or **.val()**

```
endPicker = $("#EndTime").data("kendoTimePicker").text();
```